# angular2 get optional parameter from router

Tags: angular, router, optional-parameters

I'm using angular 2 version rc4 with router version 3.0.0-beta.2.

Given this url: http://localhost:8888/#/test;status=07
I'd like to get the value of the status optional parameter.
As far as I know this code should work:

```
console.log("status", this._activatedRoute.snapshot.params['status']);
```

But I got undefined for this.
It is also interesting that this code gives me the proper value:

```
console.log("urlsegment", this._activatedRoute.snapshot['_urlSegment'].pathsWithParams[0].parameters['status']);
```

I cannot understand why?
What do I do wrong?
The second solution is very ugly so I do not really want to use it.

Any help would be welcome.

Edit:
main.ts:

```
bootstrap(App, [
   APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ..Some other stuff..]).then((appRef) => AppInjector(appRef.injector));
```

app.routes.ts:

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    {path: 'admin', component: FrontComponent, children: [...FrontRoutes]},
    {path: '', component: PublicComponent, children: [ ...PublicRoutes]}
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

public.routes.ts:

```
export const PublicRoutes: RouterConfig = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', terminal: true, canActivate:[CanActivateGuard]},
    {path: 'test', component: TestRouterComponent, children: [...TestRoutes]},
    {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardRouterComponent, children: [...DashboardRoutes]},
];
```

test.routes.ts:

```
export const TestRoutes: RouterConfig = [
    {path: '', component: TestComponent, canActivate:[CanActivateGuard]},
    {path: 'detail/:id', component: TestDetailComponent, canActivate:[CanActivateGuard]},
];
```

The way I use the router to navigate:

```
this._router.navigate(['test', {status:07}]);
```

Comment: Please post the routes and how you navigate to the current route.

Comment: `terminal: true,` was changed to `pathMatch: 'full'` a while ago.

Comment: I think you need to read `queryParams` instead.

Comment: yes, `...snapshot.queryParams['status']`. `params` is what is passed for path segments like `{ path: 'some/:status/other', ...}`

Comment: I've tried it.        console.log(this._router.routerState.snapshot.queryParams['status']);
Unfortunately this solution also gives me undefined.

Comment: I didn't say anything about `router.routerState`. You could also try `_activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => console.log(params['s‌​tatus']));`. Optional parameters are added to specific routes. If they are added to a parent or child route, you won't get them. `_activatedRoute.parent.queryParams.subscribe(params => console.log(params['s‌​tatus']));`, `_activatedRoute.firstChild.queryParams.subscribe(params => console.log(params['s‌​tatus']));`

Comment: There is no queryParams attribute in the router in this version 3.0.0-beta.2. It get it in a later version I think, unfortunately I am not allowed to use newer version yet.

Comment: Ok, the problem is really that my TestComponent is a child in the routes.
If I modify the app.routes.ts like adding this to the routes:
    {path: 'test', component: TestComponent, canActivate:[CanActivateGuard]},
then it works like a charm,
The problem is that there is no parent or firstChild attribute in _activatedRoute in this version.
So I still don't know how to reach it.
But I am one step closer to the final solution.

Comment: What about updating? `parent` and `firstChild` were added recently. There  are other ways to get parent and child but I don't know them by heard. `parent` and `firstChild` are just convenience getters. You can check the source how they are implemented.

Comment: At this moment I am not allowed to update, but now I will force that make it possible as soon as possible.
If you give an answer for this question I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optional parameters are added to specific routes. If they are added to a parent or child route, you won't get them.

```
_activatedRoute.parent.queryParams.subscribe(params => console.log(params['s‌​tatus']));, _activatedRoute.firstChild.queryParams.subscribe(params => console.log(params['s‌​tatus']));
```

`parent`, `firstChild`, `children` are convenient methods added in RC.6